# "ProgrammingError at / relation "posts_post" does not exist LINE 1: ...evious_post_id", "posts_post"."next_post_id" FROM "posts_pos..."

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I just finished writing a blog app with django which works perfectly locally but on deploying, I'm getting this error "OperationalError at /
no such table: posts_post". After installing postgres, the error message changed to "ProgrammingError at / relation "posts_post" does not exist LINE 1: ...evious_post_id", "posts_post"."next_post_id" FROM "posts_pos..."
Please what can I do?

Comment: Have you migrate the model changes with command 'python manage.py migrate' on server?

Comment: Yes I have. I've gotten past that, I had to install postgres as the database. But now I'm getting another error "ProgrammingError at /
relation "posts_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ...evious_post_id", "posts_post"."next_post_id" FROM "posts_pos..."